# Deploy to Linux

Tags: linux, qt, visual-studio-2012, deployment

**Background:**

Im using QT and have visual studio 2012 as my IDE (used the QT plugin for visual studio).

And finally the whole project is done. However due to my .NET background I have no experience when it comes to deploying my project so it can be run on Linux.

**Question:**

Anyone knowing how to deploy a QT project made in visual studio to linux?

Comment: Use a cross-platform build system like QMake or CMake, install Linux (in a VM or native), build and test there.

Answer (score 1):

You should install Linux and prepare a Qt development environment on it.You can then copy your project there, compile it and see the results in the real environment. This way you can cope with the minor differences when porting from one OS to another easily.

So don't think of cross compiling your app for Linux on Windows. From a complexity point of view, I think setting up a Linux machine (VM or not) and the necessary environment for Qt is a whole lot simpler than cross compiling bug hunting afterwards. After all you will need a real target environment to finally test your application.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can deploy something you have to compile it for that platform, and here you have two main choiches: either you cross-compile which means you compile it on windows using a set of tools so that your software is built to run on a linux, or you get a linux machine, you copy your entire project over and let Qt for linux do the magic.

Once you have your working binary compiled on linux or for linux then you start thnking about deployoment.

If you really want to be fully linux-compatible and "linux-ally correct" you should distribute your source-code precooked using some tools like "automake" that will make it possible to linux users to compile it on any linux version.

If you do not want to release your source code, you technically can distribute binaries without source code (not sure if you will be ok with licenses)  but you have to be aware that there is no standard in linux for distributing binary packages, there are at least 2 main package building standards that are the ubuntu/debian style and red hat (and friends) style.
You are going to find plenty of documentation about all this stuff from cross-compile to automake and of course building debian packages and building red hat rpm packages.